# Dynamically change style Url in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have multiple scss component. I want to load specific scss component according to selected theme.
For example:
I have 2 theme: Theme1.component.scss and theme2.component.scss and I can select one theme and save it in the database. According to that I want to load home page with selected theme.

Comment: can you support code for your Question??

Comment: Would this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952475/change-styles-scss-dynamically-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

No need to keep multiple style components. Create a single style sheet use it like a pro. everywhere

use css global varibles which is defined like

`--btn-color:'something'`

and you can manipulate it using directive or service directly.

change the

`--btn-color:'something'` accordingly to get apply any theme

`private themeWrapper = document.querySelector("body");`

```
this.themeWrapper.style.setProperty("--btn-color","red");
```